# 0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ^ (cURL problem)

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, http, wit.ai

I just start to use wit.AI to create my first bot and I'm doing everything in backend.
I first create my server.
Now I just want to do some request with cURL but when I copy the model  which provided by wit.AI I have an error:

[this what I have to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d8ck.png)

[this is what I got in GIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtDIj.png)

Thanks a lot for everyone who will be able to help !

At first I thought the problem was my server access so I just generate a new token but my problem was still the same.

Comment: Please post text information as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carats (`^`) are there to indicate that it's supposed to be one continuous command, just broken across several lines for easier human consumption. Take them out of the command that you run.